# how to display xml content with php

Tags: php, html, xml, dom

I want to display my **xml** file content on the navigator. In the **PHP** file I call a function witch create and write an xml file using **DOM**. Now I want to display the result file 'result.xml'.
I tried with the header:`header("Content-Type: text/plain");` but I get all the HTML code shown on the web page. I just want to show the xml content not the whole HTML code of the page.
Is there any function which I can use? or should I read the xml file as an .txt file and then show it containts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can redirect to this file:

```
<?php header('Location: '.$xmlFile); ?>
```

Your browser will dispay the content of the file

Comment: It works but I want to display it on my page not opening it. I don't want to redirect to another file . thank you

Answer (score 3):

Your header should be

```
header('Content-Type: text/xml');
```

For RAW XML Output..

```
header('Content-Type: application/xml');
```

---

#### An example..

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/xml');
$output = "<Bikes><Name>Ducati</Name></Bikes>";
print ($output);
```

Comment: I get errors using these header This page contains the following errors:

error on line 1 at column 1: Document is empty
Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.

Comment: Is your `XML` generated properly ? Can you test the example given on my answer ?

Comment: The above example works fine. Anyways.. can you post the code on your question ?

Comment: I want to show the php echo messages and then the xml output as a text

Comment: You can not output different content at the same time, you have to output the XML to the browser (as described by this answer) or the HTML. Not both at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
<?php echo htmlspecialchars(file_get_contents('product.xml')); ?>
```